# Mathematical astrophysics subjects for math graduate students

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, mathematical-astronomy

I'm looking for a cool and interesting subject in mathematical astrophysics to study for my master's project. What I really aim for is certain processes in the cosmos (multiple body-problem, black holes, asteroid belts, colliding stellar objects, etc...), but my background is not very much on the physics side, unfortunately. However, I read about special relativity, gravitational waves and how to measure in space, but not in a very mathematical way.

I would like to hear from someone whether they know similar subjects like the above that are reachable for a graduate math student, like me, to study for their master's project.

My background is mainly in algebra (Galois, Geometry, crypto), but I also have done statistical data analysis courses and (P)DE courses; thus I have seen a rich part of mathematics, but my specialty is really in abstract algebra. However, especially now, I would like to get to know subjects that are not mainly abstract algebra, but more PDE, for example.

I'm ready to dive into depths of mathematical physics if necessary. Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Hi, mathematical physics student here. A good way to get started is to learn classical mechanics: Newtonian, Lagrangian, and Hamiltonian. Definitely learn Fourier Series and Transforms. And good knowledge about differential equations, both ordinary and partial, is indispensable. After that, more advanced subjects like general relativity will require tensor calculus and differential geometry. Hopefully this is a good list to point you in the right direction!

Comment: Oh, and how could I forget quantum mechanics: that will require a lot of linear algebra.

Comment: @K.defaoite Hmm, you can't say PDE without Fourier, so I got all that covered from the bachelor. Also differential geometry and knowledge about tensor algebras I already have. To come back to your comment, I'm not going to learn all fundamental physics, I just want to apply my mathematics there and learn some physics as I go. I didn't study physics, but with my background I will be able to jump in further in the story for I can always just view it from a mathematical standing point; it's a math project after all.

Comment: PDEs, maths but with a astrophysics application? Try magneto-convection.